# How to make an object's vertex follow another object

Tags: objects, vertices, constraints, parent

How do I make an object's vertex follow another object?

(Not to be confused with: How to make the object follow another object's vertex)

Comment: The hook modifier?.  https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### This can be done with the *Hook* modifier.

To hook vertices from "object A" to "object B", first assign all vertices of object **A** which you want to "follow" object **B** to a vertex group.  Then add a hook modifier to object **A** and select the vertex group you have created and object **B** in their respective boxes on the modifier.

[image]