# Make a point in a line follow an object

Tags: modeling

I have a line that connects two objects. I would like that when one of those objects moves, the points on the line follows the objects, so the line always connects both objects. 
[image]
How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

Use hooks.

Hooks will allow you to parent vertices (or control points in a curve)
to empties or vertices in other objects, so that the deformations are controlled by the parented element.

read the following links:

[Attaching a curve by its endpoints to two spheres](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13452/attaching-a-curve-by-its-endpoints-to-two-spheres/13463#13463)

[Is it possible to assign a parent to a control point of a curve using animall?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14760/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-parent-to-a-control-point-of-a-curve-using-animall/14763#14763)

[How to make an object's vertex follow another object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43487/how-to-make-an-objects-vertex-follow-another-object/43489#43489)

[How to make a wiggly animated curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91185/how-to-make-a-wiggly-animated-curve/91220#91220)

[Dotted line on curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21060/dotted-line-on-curve)

Comment: Thanks, that was useful